# Change CSS depends on what user chose

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

#### Background and problem

On my Rails app, users can create their names and choose sex. On their profile page, both of their name and sex are already shown correctly. Next, I would like to change the color of their name depend on their sex instead of showing both name and sex, but it doesn't work well so far. I would appreciate if anyone teach it to me.

#### Users/edit.html.erb

```
       <%= form_tag("/users/#{@user.id}/update", {multipart: true}) do %>
        <table>
          <p>User name</p>
            <input name="name" value="<%= @user.name %>">
          <p>Sex</p>
            <select name="sex" value="<%= @user.sex %>" selected><%= @user.sex %>>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
            </select>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </table>
       <% end %>
```

#### Users/show.html.erb

```
    <div class="user">
      <div class="username"><%= @user.name %></div>
      <div class="sex"><%= "(" + @user.sex + ")" %></div>
    </div>
```

#### What I've tried

I edited **Users/show.html.erb** like this, but it doesn't work.

```
      <div class="username">
        <%= @user.name %>
          <% if @user.sex == "Male" %>
            <% @user.name color: blue; %>
          <% elsif @user.sex == "Female" %>
            <% @user.name color: red; %>
          <% else %>
            <% @user.name color: black; %>
          <% end %>
      </div>
```

I will add more code if it needs to be refered. Thank you very much.

#### Version

ruby 2.6.4p104 / RubyGems 3.0.3 / Rails 5.2.3

Comment: "it doesn't work well so far" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the sex info directly as `classname`.

```
<style>
  .username span{
    color: black;
  }
  .username span.Male{
    color: blue;
  }
  .username span.Female{
    color: red;
  }
</style>
<div class="username">
  <span class="<%= @user.sex %>"><%= @user.name %></span>
</div>
```

Comment: great! glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest way to do this is to use helper method:

```
<div class="username #{username_color(@user.sex)}">
  <%= @user.name %>
</div>
```

in helpers, `user_helper.rb`

```
def username_color(sex)
  case sex
  when "Male" then "blue"
  when "Female" then "red"
  else "black"
  end
end
```

and remember to tweak up your css styles

Comment: Thank you for helping me! It was the first time to use Helper for me.
But unfortunately, the color of "username" is still black after I change the sex to male and female.. I don't settle any color information on CSS.